# How can I reduce energy usage from infinite CAAnimation? (Animated Gradient)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, caanimation

I want to include an animated gradient in my application and I'm currently using CATransition for the task. However the animation has very high energy usage on both iOS as well as macOS (I develop both apps). Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this? Is there a library for that that is performing better or can I use a different animation?

The code I currently have looks like this:

```
var gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    var color = 0
    var animationGradient = [CGColor(red: 0.94, green: 0.32, blue: 0.31, alpha: 1.00),
                             CGColor(red: 0.93, green: 0.25, blue: 0.48, alpha: 1.00),
                             CGColor(red: 0.67, green: 0.28, blue: 0.74, alpha: 1.00),
                             CGColor(red: 0.50, green: 0.34, blue: 0.76, alpha: 1.00),
                             CGColor(red: 0.48, green: 0.53, blue: 0.80, alpha: 1.00),
                             CGColor(red: 0.26, green: 0.65, blue: 0.96, alpha: 1.00),
                             CGColor(red: 0.16, green: 0.71, blue: 0.96, alpha: 1.00),
                             CGColor(red: 0.15, green: 0.78, blue: 0.85, alpha: 1.00),
                             CGColor(red: 0.15, green: 0.65, blue: 0.61, alpha: 1.00),
                             CGColor(red: 0.40, green: 0.73, blue: 0.41, alpha: 1.00),
                             CGColor(red: 0.61, green: 0.80, blue: 0.40, alpha: 1.00),
                             CGColor(red: 0.83, green: 0.88, blue: 0.34, alpha: 1.00),
                             CGColor(red: 1.00, green: 0.93, blue: 0.35, alpha: 1.00),
                             CGColor(red: 1.00, green: 0.79, blue: 0.16, alpha: 1.00),
                             CGColor(red: 1.00, green: 0.65, blue: 0.15, alpha: 1.00),
                             CGColor(red: 1.00, green: 0.44, blue: 0.26, alpha: 1.00)]
    var animationIndex = 0
    var fromColors: [CGColor] = []
    var toColors: [CGColor] = []

func createGradient() {
        fromColors = [CGColor(red: 1.00, green: 1.00, blue: 1.00, alpha: 1.00),
                      CGColor(red: 1.00, green: 1.00, blue: 1.00, alpha: 1.00)]
        toColors = [CGColor(red: 0.67, green: 0.28, blue: 0.74, alpha: 1.00),
                    CGColor(red: 0.16, green: 0.71, blue: 0.96, alpha: 1.00)]

        gradient.colors = fromColors
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
        gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)

        self.view.layer?.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 100)

        animateLayer(withDuration: 0.5)
    }

    func animateLayer(withDuration duration: Double){
        var animation = CATransition()
        animation.duration = duration
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
        animation.fillMode = .forwards
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
        animation.delegate = self as? CAAnimationDelegate
        animation.type = .fade
        self.gradient.add(animation, forKey:"animateGradient")
        gradient.colors = toColors
    }

    func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        self.fromColors = toColors
        color = (color + Int.random(in: 2...6)) % animationGradient.count
        toColors = [fromColors[1],
                    animationGradient[color]]
        animateLayer(withDuration: 6.00)
    }
```

The code works just fine and the animation works, however the performance is terrible. Does anyone have a better solution? I'm happy about any tips!

Comment: Hmm.. can you show where you are using it and how? IE: Where are those functions called?

Comment: sure delegate method is called `self as? CAAnimationDelegate`

Comment: The function createGradient() is called once in the viewDidLoad() and takes it from there. After that all the code that is needed is the one above. I could post the entire ViewController but that would fill many pages :D

Comment: The self as? CAAnimationDelegate is not really necessary you're right, but setting the delegate is, because of the func animationDidStop. That's part of the CAAnimationDelegate. I also obviously inherited CAAnimationDelegate to my ViewController.